# formatter deserialize gives: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, exception, binary, formatter

I am trying to deserialize an object I saved to a file (with Binary Formatter). Whatever I try, I get the exception: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

I have the following lines of code:

```c#
public static T DeserializeFromBinaryFile<T>(string fileName)
{
    T instance = default(T);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        instance = (T)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch{}
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

I also tried:

```c#
public static T DeserializeFromBinaryFile<T>(string fileName)
{
    T instance = default(T);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        instance = (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        ms.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

But whatever I do, always get the exception:

> End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

**ADDITION**:
I just did some extra tests. If I have a simple object, just a few properties, it works just fine. Using a more (big) complex object, having other objects, enums, etc. encapsulated, that's when I get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `position` to `0` for your stream, inside of the second try/catch block:

```
BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
s.Position = 0;
return (YourObjectType)b.Deserialize(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to deserialize the filestream rather than the memorystream?
it works for me.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
fs.position=0;
instance = (T)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Every member within the class to be serialized, must have the `[Serializable()]` attribute or be marked `[NonSerialized]`. Note, enums and all simple built in types are already serializable and do not require the `[Serializable()]` attribute.

The example below gives the same error. Uncomment the `[Serializable()]` above `public class B`, and deserialization will occur without errors.

**It is not possible to say with certainty whether this is the cause of your error, because you did not provide a sample of the class resulting in the error.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; 

//[Serializable()]
public class B
{
    public int y = 2;
}
[Serializable()]
public class A
{
    public int x = 2;
    /*[NonSerialized]*/ public B b;
    public static T DeserializeFromBinaryFile<T>(string fileName)
    {
        T instance = default(T);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            instance = (T)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }

        return instance;
    }
    public static void SerializeBinaryFile<T>(string fileName,T t)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(fs, t);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A testA = new A();
        A.SerializeBinaryFile("test.dat", testA);
        A testReadA = A.DeserializeFromBinaryFile<A>("test.dat");
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx